# Backbone Marionette, rendering composite view twice?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have this issue that prints user data twice, this is the code:

```
window.UserData = {}
UserData.Model = Backbone.Model.extend();
UserData.Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/test.php?c=userData',
  model: UserData.Model,
  parse: function (response) {
    return response.data;
  }
});
UserData.View = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  tagName: 'span',
  template: Handlebars.compile($('#user-data-template').html())
});
BaseApp.Layout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
  template: Handlebars.compile($('#base-layout-template').html()),
  regions: {
    'region_user_data': '#user_data_reg'
  },
  initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this);
  },
  onRender: function () {
    var self = this;
    var c = new UserData.Collection();
    c.fetch({
      success: function () {
        var ud = new UserData.View({
          collection: c
        });
        self.region_user_data.show(ud);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

this BaseApp Layout is being rendered once on a region (in body).

This is the template:

```
<script id='user-data-template' type='text/x-handlebars-template'>
    <a href="#" id="logout"> Logout </a> Hola {{uname}}
</script>

<script id='base-layout-template' type='text/x-handlebars-template'>
    base page layout
    <div id="user_data_reg" class="user_data_reg"></div>
</script>
```

this is what is being shown in the browser (chrome):

```
Logout Hola Logout Hola 14
```

As you can see it displays the user layout twice but the first time does not displays the uname, it is kind of weird because in chrome I have this:

```
child {models: Array[0], length: 0, _byId: Object, 
constructor: function, url: "http://localhost/test.php?c=userData"…}
```

the model is being displayed only 1 and what it does is that prints twice content.

Also when I fetch the collection data I do this:

```
c.fetch({
  success: function () {
    var ud = new UserData.View({
      collection: c
    });
    self.region_user_data.show(ud);
    console.log("print xx");
  }
```

and it only logs "print xx" only once & not twice as I expected.

Why am I getting double userData content even if the collection is fetching only a single model, why is this happening?
Regards.

Comment: After fetching data, **c** collection contains with what? Maybe it's array like that ["", "14"].

Comment: Can you share the code that news up the BaseApp.Layout and renders it?

Comment: @bob it is not an array as I explanied a while ago in:child {models: Array[0], length: 0, _byId: Object.
Regards.

Comment: @ScottPuleo "this BaseApp Layout is being rendered once on a region (in body).".
I have posted an answer about the Issue, thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an issue with the view type, instead of using "CompositeView" I switched to ItemView and the problem went away. I guess Marionette forces to use ItemView for single data.